# PrintScreen de segundo plano em Java

Tags: java, image

Galera quero saber se tem como eu tirar print de um programa rodando em segundo plano
Atualmente uso o comando :

```
try {
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(valor3,valor4,189,24));
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:\\OCR\\test.jpg"));
}
```

Funciona de boas com programa rodando em primeiro plano, mas queria que ele tirasse foto de um programa que estivesse rodando em segundo plano, com esse comando ele tira foto do que ta na tela sempre... 
Alguém da uma luz ai pf!

Comment: Pode adicionar um [mcve] do seu código funciionando apenas com o modo primeiro plano?